# Incorrect Error Squiggles In Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, struct

I am currently writing a C program with a struct called `Rectangle`. The code below shows how I set it up.

```
typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    int x;
    int y;
} Rectangle;
```

After that, I made another struct called `Ellipse` which contained exactly the same values as the `Rectangle` struct, as well as some more.
I wanted to keep my code neat so I decided to make a base struct called `Shape`.
I used this `Shape` struct in the header of my other structs.

```
typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    int x;
    int y;
} Shape;

typedef struct {
    Shape shape;
} Rectangle;

typedef struct {
    Shape shape;
    int angle;
    int anchor_x;
    int anchor_y;
} Ellipse;
```

Now whenever I make an instance of one of these structs, VSCode thinks there's an error.

```
Rectangle *rect;
rect -> width = 100;
```

VSCode puts an error squiggle under `width` that says `struct "<unnamed>" has no field "width"`, but when I compile the code, it works perfectly.

Why does VSCode raise this error? Should I be doing things differently? How can I stop it from making unnecessary squiggles?

Please be patient, I am new to C programming.

Comment: Please note that "squiggles" of an IDE are commonly independent of the errors and warnings the compiler will produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a field `width` inside `Rectangle` - you have a field `shape`. Presumably what you wanted to do is `rect->shape.width = 100`.

Notice that your code won't work as-is because you never allocate memory for `rect`.